# From where alsa getting their default states?

Tags: linux, controls, restore, alsa, mixer

I am trying to get knowledge on alsa. When I saw it, it is automatically storing the previous states of the mixer controls and restoring them in the reboots. So I commented this process from the files `/etc/init/alsa-restore.conf`  `/etc/init/alsa-store.conf` . After that I make one control to True and rebooted my system. After rebooting I checked the value of the control which is false now.

From where alsa get that control value as false after reboot.

There is no file `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` because I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial state of mixer controls is determined either by the driver or by the device itself.

Furthermore, when `asound.state` does not yet exist, many distributions will call `alsactl init`.

If you want a mixer control to have a specific value, you must set this value somehow.
If you don't want to rely on `asound.state`, you could run your own script that sets the control with `amixer`.

Answer (score 0):

To edit alsamixer settings in linux

use command:

`$ alsamixer`

just type `alsamixer` to open alsamixer in terminal